# Bar code generation in Java

Tags: java, barcode

Which is a better bar code generation library in Java. I see two options as JBar and Barbecue.
Any real life usage is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried [Barcode4J](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/). Nice one

Answer (score 4):

I think Barbecue is an open-source & easy Java library so it is best.Also ZXing (pronounced “zebra crossing”) is an open-source, multi-format 1D/2D barcode image processing library implemented in Java.See this link http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Answer (score 2):

I prefer barbecue, is more stable and simple

[example here(http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/barcodes/barbecue/barcode-size.html)

```
public class BarCodeSizeTest {

public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {

//Get 128B Barcode instance from the Factory
Barcode barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128B("be the coder");
barcode.setBarHeight(60);
barcode.setBarWidth(2);

File imgFile = new File("testsize.png");

//Write the bar code to PNG file
BarcodeImageHandler.savePNG(barcode, imgFile);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Barbecue](http://barbecue.sourceforge.net).

Simple example is really trivial:

```
BufferedImage image = BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(BarcodeFactory.createCode128("BARCODE"));
```

Afterwards you can convert *image* to a *byte[]* via *ByteArrayOutputStream*.

Answer (score 0):

I have used "**zxing**"

Have the following dependencies,

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/javase

```
QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(inputText, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filePath);
MatrixToImageWriter.writeToPath(bitMatrix, "PNG", path);
```

you can convert into image using,

```
Image image = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(bitMatrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, I would consider https://github.com/woo-j/OkapiBarcode

Barbecue and Barcode4j are not maintained since a very long time.